# Distinguir touch de scrolling

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, touch

Estoy haciendo una aplicación que se usará en pantallas táctiles. El problema que tengo es que no se como distinguir entre el scrolling y el simple touch.

Tengo un scrollviewer que contiene un stackpanel donde voy añadiendo imagenes. La idea es que cuando se toque una imagen se abra a pantalla completa un video asociado, pero la lista es grande y se debe poder hacer scrolling. Ahora mismo si arrastro encima de la imagen, me abre directamente el video. No se como diferenciar el evento de scroll con el evento de simple touch.

```
        <ScrollViewer Name="viewer" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Margin="0,50,0,0" PanningMode="VerticalOnly" PanningDeceleration="0" PanningRatio="1">
        <StackPanel Name="pnlVideos" Orientation="Vertical"></StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

Las imagenes las añado desde el codigo C# y les asocio el evento TouchDown.

```
 img = new Image();
 img.Width = 400;
 img.Height = 225;
 img.Name = "img_" + j;
 img.TouchDown += PlayVideo;
 img.Margin = new Thickness(20, 10, 0, 0);
 img.Tag = thumb.FullName;
```

Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Buenas Fernando, bienvenido a [es.so]. Recuerda leer el [tour] para aprender como funciona el sitio. mhh no conozco a fondo esas tecnologias  pero igual existe algun evento de TouchUp (veo que tienes touchDown ahora mismo) o parecido para que detecte el click al levantar el raton/dedo y si no se ha desplazado entonces mostrar el video. Mira [ask] para mejorar la informacion y calidad de la pregunta. Un saludo

Comment: Finalmente lo he solucionado cambiando el evento a un mousedown. Con el táctil funciona de igual modo. Gracias a todos.

Comment: Entonces, puedes redactar una respuesta para asi autocontestarte (es perfectamente válido en el sitio). En 48h podrás marcar tu propia respuesta como aceptada. Un saludo

Comment: Esto es un ejemplo de por qué Chrome quitó el soporte para los eventos touch en 2016 (aunque no sé si algo habrá cambiado desde entonces). No se podía diferenciar entre un click o el inicio de un scroll, y eso podía usarse desde contenido en marcos (p.e. anuncios y contenido de terceros) para aceptar interacciones que realmente no lo eran, potencialmente creando problemas de experiencia de usuario y de seguridad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finalmente lo he solucionado cambiando el evento de las imagenes a MouseDown.

```
 img.MouseDown += PlayVideo;
```